# Java pattern matching for validation

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching

I need to validate a String. Ex: AABCAd. In this string 'A' can occur n number of times. But continuously it can occur only twice not more than that. Example for invalid string is AAAXCA. Since it occurred more than 2 times continuously. I need to validate the string using pattern matching.  Please provide help.

Comment: how many characters are allowed? How the chars will looks like? only word characters?

Comment: And what are the issues that you have found with your current code?

Comment: Please post your current code that you've got to validate it, or at least some code that attempts to validate it.

Comment: All, In a given string a character cannot occur more than two continuously as mentioned in Example 2. 'A' occurred 3 times continuously which is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead at the start for checking the appearance of `A` in a string.

```
"^(?!.*AAA)\\w+$"
```

`(?!.*AAA)` negative lookahead asserts that the string going to be match won't contain atleast three consecutive `A`'s.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pT4tM5/27)

Comment: you don't need to check for 3 or more. Just 3 would be fine.

Comment: Thank you so much it answerd my question. <code>String aa="^(?!.*(AAA))\\w+$";
  if("AAXCCDA".matches(aa)){
   System.out.println("YES");
   
  }</code>